# Change Jupyter notebook tab-autocomplete font color in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am working with Jupyter notebooks in a Jupyter Lab setting over which I have limited control. After a recent update, I noticed that the tooltip font color for tab-autocompletion is very difficult to read:

[image: Example of poor contrast in tooltip font color]

How can I change the font color to make it more legible?

Comment: What version of JupyterLab are you running? This qualifies as a bug report, not as a question on how to change color I think.

Comment: Version 2.2.9, would be a shame if it were a bug... was hoping not to deal with it

Comment: Reporting bugs is not difficult, please just follow [the guidelines](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/issue.html). Now, to understand what is going on here you would need to use you browser developer tools to [inspect styles](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css) on these elements. Also, do you have any jupyter theme installed?